# Linguistics relativity and linguistic determinism

Tags: psycholinguistics, linguistic-determinism

What is the difference between linguistic relativity and linguistic determinism ?
 any suggestions for books to read concerning these topics !

Comment: (Wikipedia) [*Linguistic determinism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_determinism) is the "general" principle that language determines/limits human knowledge or thought, as well as thought processes such as categorization, memory, and perception. *Linguistic relativity* (popularly known as the Sapir–Whorf hypothesis) is ***a form of linguistic determinism*** which argues that individuals experience the world based on the structure of the language they habitually use.

Comment: Improve your question by a) re-phrasing the question title as a question, and b) citing some of your previous attempts to find answers to this question from other sources

Answer (score 1):

Linguistic **determinism** is a broader philosophical and psycholinguistic question about the relationship between thought and language.

Linguistic **relativity** is a position that 1. the relationship between linguistic structures and structures of thought (and cognition) is deterministic AND 2. it applies to particular structures of particular languages and their speakers. Namely, different languages cause their speakers to think differently from each other in fundamental ways.

The reading list for this issue is quite long. The current proponent of this position is [Lera Boroditsky](http://lera.ucsd.edu/papers/) and her publications will provide further references. I always liked Lakoff's summary of the issues in chapter 18 of *Women, Fire and Dangerous Things*. And the edited volume [Rethinking Linguistic Relativity](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dPXvxgL2t1oC&redir_esc=y) will provide a good overview.

One of the most vociferous opponents of relativity is the philosopher Jerry Fodor. Some of the contra arguments and literature can be found [here](http://stanford.library.usyd.edu.au/archives/sum2015/entries/relativism/index.html#5).

Answer (score 0):

John McWhorter also addresses the deterministic position on linguistic relativity in *Why the World Looks the Same in Every Language*. McWhorter holds that there is quite a bit of evidence for this determinism, all of which, however, is light years away from constituting a world view. In other words, the evidence for a fundamental relationship between language and culture remains thin. A moment's reflection will bear this out: people who speak the same language have wildly different world views.